# Servlet being called twice!

Tags: java, servlets

sorry but I do not have the actual code with me, but I will try to explain:

I have a servlet mapped to the following:

```
/admin/*
```

So, this goes to a servlet:

```
public class AdminController extends MainController {
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        // Do stuf here
    }
}
```

Here is MainController:

```
public class MainController extends HttpServlet {
@Override
public void service(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response) {
    String requesturi = ((HttpServletRequest)request).getRequestURI();
    reqlist = Arrays.asList(requesturi.substring(requesturi.indexOf(Util.rootPath) + Util.rootPath.length()).split("/"));
    reqlist = reqlist.subList(1, reqlist.size());

    doPost((HttpServletRequest)request, (HttpServletResponse)response);
}
```

So, the request is passed to AdminController, no problem, but then I reallized something:

**The servlet is being called twice!**. And this is causing me many errors..

Does anybody have a clue on this? It is because I used some kind of heritance? 
Thank you for all!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [HttpServlet.service](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/2.3/javadoc/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html#service(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)) method gets called for all request types and what you are seeing is a HEAD request and then a GET or POST request. Instead of implementing service just implement doGet or doPost. What is commonly done is to just implement one of doPost or doGet and then call the other from the one you don't have an implementation for.

Comment: Hi,  I am facing the same problem...and I have implemented  the doPost() method  only...but every time I am facing this issue even  my website has been  hosted..I have created a link to call that servlet ...Pls help

Answer (score 11):

Though it is old thread but my answer may help someone.
Today I faced the same issue. My particular servlet is working fine earlier and suddenly it has started calling doGet method twice. On investigation, I found that my chrome browser has html validator extension which is calling the servlet again with same request to do html validation.
After I disabling the extension, the problem got resolved.

Comment: After 3 hours of searching through the doFilter code, web descriptor, filter-mappings, this saved my downhill road. I love you. :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, GitLab extension caused this for me

Answer (score 2):

I solved same problem with simple way.

If you are developing local and access to your app with address http://127.0.0.1 which is loopback network, change address to http://localhost which is direct.

This problem won't happen if you actually run it on webhosting or server and access to it from outer network.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, and I tried anything mentioned above and on other posts, but the issue was only on local.

If nothing works for you too, try a deploy :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I had a servlet to handle a post request.
But after calling doPost it suddenly started to call doGet method.
So the doGet was called by a chrome plugin that I installed (FireBug Lite).
Problem solved after I deactivated that plugin.